# JS Function won't create another qr code object when called again

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, qr-code

I am using a javascript file called qrcode.js (https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs).

What I am trying to do is take an input from the user and then call a javascript function (createQRCode) from my c# code behind to create multiple QR codes.

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "createQRCode('tr1c1', 'www.google.com')", true);
    tr1c1Label.Text = "www.google.com";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "createQRCode('tr1c2', 'www.reddit.com')", true);
    tr1c2Label.Text = "www.reddit.com";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "createQRCode('tr1c3', 'www.stackoverflow.com')", true);
    tr1c3Label.Text = "www.stackoverflow.com";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "createQRCode('tr2c1', 'www.twitter.com')", true);
    tr2c1Label.Text = "www.twitter.com";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "createQRCode('tr2c2', 'www.facebook.com')", true);
    tr2c2Label.Text = "www.facebook.com";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "createQRCode('tr3c1', 'www.myspace.com')", true);
    tr3c1Label.Text = "www.myspace.com";
}
```

Once the submit button is clicked, it calls this javascript function multiple times:

```
function createQRCode(div, url) {
        var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById(div), {
            text: url,
            width: 128,
            height: 128,
            colorDark: "#000000",
            colorLight: "#ffffff",
            correctLevel: QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
        });
    };
```

The code behind passes a div to create the qr code in and a url to put in the qr code. This works but only once. It calls the javascript function every time, but doesn't generate a new qr code. It only creates the first one and it is correct.
Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[QR Code Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngyGQ.png)

My question is **How can I get the javascript to create a new QR code everytime the function is called?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know c# but I think the error is in

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "createQRCode('tr1c2', 'www.reddit.com')", true);
```

The identifier(3rd argument) MUST be unique for every script!
Try this:

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction1", "createQRCode('tr1c1', 'www.google.com')", true);
tr1c1Label.Text = "www.google.com";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction2", "createQRCode('tr1c2', 'www.reddit.com')", true);
tr1c2Label.Text = "www.reddit.com";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction3", "createQRCode('tr1c3', 'www.stackoverflow.com')", true);
tr1c3Label.Text = "www.stackoverflow.com";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction4", "createQRCode('tr2c1', 'www.twitter.com')", true);
tr2c1Label.Text = "www.twitter.com";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction5", "createQRCode('tr2c2', 'www.facebook.com')", true);
tr2c2Label.Text = "www.facebook.com";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction6", "createQRCode('tr3c1', 'www.myspace.com')", true);
tr3c1Label.Text = "www.myspace.com";
```

}

Comment: I tried this but now no QR codes are showing up. Not even the first one.

Comment: Actually, your solution did work. I was forgetting the semicolon in each line.